# Swift: Keep mouse pointer from leaving window

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I have a Mac SpriteKit / swift app (a game) where I need to keep the cursor within a window. or at least give some warning when it leaves the game window.

I already have a tracking area set up and am using the mouse to move a game paddle. But when the cursor moves outside the window, the paddle stops working.

```
 let options = [ .mouseMoved,
                .activeAlways,
                .mouseEnteredAndExited] as NSTrackingArea.Options
let tracker = NSTrackingArea(rect:frame, options: options, owner:view, userInfo: nil)
view.addTrackingArea(tracker)
```

The mouse entered and exited functions don't seem to fire

```
override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
   // NSCursor.unhide()
    print("_____________________EXIT")
   //Never fires

  }

  override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
 //   NSCursor.hide()
    print("_____________________ENTER")
 // never fires

  }
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: If this code is in GameScene.swift (or another SKScene subclass), the `owner` argument should be `self` not `view`.

Comment: Thank you !! That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the mouse in the window you can use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`. It sets the mouse cursor position on screen.

Here's an example, to keep the mouse centered in a view:

```swift
NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) { (event) -> NSEvent? in

    let point = NSPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 0.5, y: self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
    let pointInWindow = self.view.convert(point, to: nil)
    if let pointOnScreen = self.view.window?.convertPoint(toScreen: pointInWindow) {
        let cgPoint = CGPoint(x: pointOnScreen.x, y: pointOnScreen.y)
        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(cgPoint)
    }               

    return event
}
```

Note: use `NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents` in that case to get `.mouseMoved` events instead of `NSTrackingArea`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be happier with a different solution: hide the cursor and disconnect mouse movement from the cursor position.

You can hide and show the pointer using `CGDisplayHideCursor` and `CGDisplayShowCursor`.

You can disconnect mouse movement from the cursor position (and reconnect it) using `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition`. When you receive `mouseMoved` and `mouseDragged` events while the mouse is disconnected from the cursor, you can read the mouse movement out of the `deltaX` and `deltaY` fields of the events.